# How call updated method every 10 minutes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to update my data every 10 minutes by making a request, how to do it using setInterval

```
   getDashboards() {
      //fetch here but now just mock
        return Promise.resolve(true).then(function (value) {
            return KPI
        })
    }

   componentDidUpdate() {
   
     setInterval(()=>{
        this.getDashboards().then(data => {
            this.dashboards = data
        })
   }, time)
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what is not working as expected? Where did you declare 'time'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

You probably want to set the interval in the `componentDidMount()` method:

> componentDidMount() is invoked immediately after a component is mounted ... This method is a good place to set up any subscriptions.

And remember the interval handle `this.myUpdateHandle = setInterval( ...`, so you can remove the interval when you unmount the component with `clearInterval(this.myUpdateHandle)` in React's `componentWillUnmount()` method.

> componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method...

Finally, state if usually updated with `this.setState()` so that data changes are automatically re-rendered.